# Loop to copy master data one by one, apply to data base, refresh data base & accumulate results in one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am expecting loop which can copy values one by one from master data column , apply to cell which is linked to my data base , refresh data base , copy values from table which is linked to data base & then accumulate them in one sheet.

Following are the simple code from Macro recording for two set of procedure , I want to repeat this till blank value in master data column.

```
Sheets("Base Summary").Select
Range("T3:W3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Range("B3:R6").Select
Range("R6").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("E1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Base Summary").Select
Range("T4:W4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Range("B3:R6").Select
Range("R6").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("E1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Hi H.K., you could do this with a Do While Loop. You would put the code you have recorded inside, however it will need to be updated slightly to make sure it works on the right row, let us know if you get stuck http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Comment: Yes, I resolved it , Thanks a lot for your guidance.